# still problem with alignment in references

Tags: bibliographies, horizontal-alignment

I found a link in the community with a solution for my problem that was [natbib will not auto-indent and \bibhang is not recognized](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154622/natbib-will-not-auto-indent-and-bibhang-is-not-recognized)

The solution was proposed by Gonzalo Medina but in my case happens a weird thing because the numeration. I put `\setlength\bibindent{0.5em}` (this code is present in the Gonzalo's solution). From [1] to [9], the references are aligned correctly. From [10] to [70], the references are bad aligned. When I put `\setlength\bibindent{1.0em}`, the references from [10] to [70] become right and from [1] to [9] become wrong. You can see in the picture:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Code:

```
\documentclass[pt,oneside,onehalfspacing,msc]{risethesis}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage[numbers,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[small]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}



\captionsetup[table]{position=top,justification=centering,width=.85\textwidth,labelfont=bf,font=small}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{position=top,justification=centering,width=.85\textwidth,labelfont=bf,font=small}
\captionsetup[figure]{position=bottom,justification=centering,width=.85\textwidth,labelfont=bf,font=small}


\begin{document}


\renewcommand\bibname{Referências}

\begin{references}
\bibliography{references}
\end{references}

\end{document}
```

The bib file:

```
@article{Alves,
 address              = {USA, Atlanta},
 author               = {Alves, V. M. O. and Cavalcanti, G. D. C.},
 journal              = {Proceedings of IEEE International Joint Conference on Neural Networks},
 pages                = {133--140},
 title                = {Tree architecture pattern distributor: a task decomposition classification approach},
 year                 = {2009},
 }

@book{arvoresDecisao,
 author               = {Mitchell, T. M.},
 publisher            = {McGraw-Hill},
 title                = {Machine learning},
 year                 = {1997},
 }
```

Comment: Please provide a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) so that we could help you. What happened when you give `\setlength\bibindent{0em}` instead?

Comment: with \setlength\bibindent{0em} all references become bad aligned. i.e, the second line does not match with the beginning of the first line. this problem is driving me crazy. it is requirement of my university. the code that i put in my preambule came from the link that i referenced above from \makealetter to \makeatother

Comment: Please post a minimal example here which replicate the problem. Help us to help you :-)

Comment: i dont know how to put the code to appear correctly.

Comment: i guess a solution. is there a way to convert the first reference [ 1 ] to [ 01 ] and do this to the references from 2 to 9?

Comment: That is not the ideal way to go. To place the code, just copy a minimal example which can repeat the error with `\documentclass{<your class>} ...\begin{document} ...\end{document}`.

Comment: this information that you ask me do not fit in this box

Comment: You should update your question by appending the code.

Comment: @diogosevero - You can edit your own posting. (Don't post the code to a comment.)

Comment: sorry, kurt. i will delete the two questions soon.

Comment: Untested, but try setting `\bibindent` to something large like `1em` or `1.5em`, and also issue `\renewcommand\bibnumfmt[1]{\hphantom{[999]}\llap{[#1]}}`. The idea is to redefine the labelling command so that it will save room for a three digit number and print the [1] right-aligned in that space.

Comment: BTW, if you want to reply to me and get my attention, include my user handle in your comment response and prepend it with the symbol @. The same way it was done by Mico in [this comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321471/still-problem-with-alignment-in-references#comment785795_321471) to get your attention. Otherwise I won't be notified of your response and I just by chance saw your responses to my suggestions on the other thread.

Comment: @WillieWong with bibnumfmt i got a error. bibnumfmt is undefined. is it necessary a package or something like that?

Comment: @diogosevero `\bibnumfmt` is defined by `natbib`. Since `natbib` is loaded by your document class, it should be there. Let me check a few things.

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer*: The following is not tested with the `risethesis` class that you are using. And since the code you pasted above does not do the "correct thing" according to the standard `risethesis` class's definitions, I assume you've been modifying the class file yourself, in which case you should adjust it similarly to below.

*Disclaimer 2*: The `abnt-num.bst` file that `risethesis` uses does not seem to be part of the standard distribution in TeXLive; I downloaded a copy from some random Brazilian website. Hopefully it is the same one you are using.

#### Answer

If you load `natbib` with the `numbers` option, and redefine the `\bibnumfmt` as suggested in the manual, it seems you can get away without even needing to play with indents.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

% Change the placeholder 999 below to the widest number you need 
\renewcommand\bibnumfmt[1]{\hphantom{[999]}\llap{[#1]}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{abnt-num}
\bibliography{mixmaster.bib}  % <--- For testing, replace this by your own bib tile

\end{document}
```

#### Sample output

[image]